# Python: solve uncontrained least squares

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a unconstrained least-squares problem. Let's say, the function is min ||AX+b||2, where A is a n*k matrix, X is a k*1 vector and b is a n*1 matrix. My question is: how do I get the vector X for the minimization of function f using Python?

Thank you in advance.
Kan

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html